# Partialview overwriting main view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am learning ASP.NET MVC and am trying to get my head around partial views. Im trying a very simple thing and here is my source code.

_Layout.cshtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

_ViewStart.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
```

HomeController.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace MvcApplication4.Controllers
{
        public class HomeController : Controller
        {
                public ActionResult Index()
                {
                        return View();
                }

                public PartialViewResult UpdateDate()
                {
                    return PartialView("Partial1");
                }
        }
}
```

Index.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>
@DateTime.Now
<br />
@{Html.RenderPartial("Partial1");}
<br />
@Html.ActionLink("Render Partial", "UpdateDate")
```

Partial1.cshtml

```
@DateTime.Now
```

Now when I click on the Render Partial link the UpdateDate action method is called but rendering the partial view overwrites the main content and I just see the contents of the partial view. Why do I lose the contents of Index.cshtml ?

What do i need to do to display the contents of Index.cshtml displayed as is and only refresh the partial view contents ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why do I lose the contents of Index.cshtml ?

Because you need to use an AJAX call. Right now all you have is a regular link, which is rendered as a standard `<a>` element and as you know when you click on an anchor in any webpage, the browser simply redirects to the url that the `href` attribute is pointing to. That's called a hyperlink and the world wide web is full of them.

So you could start by giving your link an unique id that could be used later in a custom script:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Render Partial", "UpdateDate", null, null, new { id = "myLink" })
```

also put your partial in a container:

```
<div id="myPartial">
    @{Html.RenderPartial("Partial1");}
</div>
```

and finally subscribe to the `.click()` event of this link and send an AJAX call instead of a regular redirect:

```
@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#myLink').click(function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.href,
                type: 'GET',
                cache: false,
                success: function(result) {
                    $('#myPartial').html(result);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script>
}
```

In this example I have overriden the custom scripts section in the view in order to write the javascript. But of course that's only for demonstration purposes. Good practices dictate that javascript code should be placed in separate javascript files and not mixed with the markup. So in a real world application this should be refactored to:

```
@section scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/mybundle")
}
```

Where `~/bundles/mybundle` is obviously a custom bundle that you would define in the `~/App_Start/BundleConfig.cs` file pointing to your external js.

---

Alternatively you could use an `Ajax.ActionLink` instead of a regular `Html.ActionLink`:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Render Partial", "UpdateDate", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "myPartial" })
```

But for this to work you need to include the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` script to your page. Since you are using ASP.NET MVC 4 and bundles you could include the `~/bundles/jqueryval` bundle in your _Layout:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```